# React app appears blank with no errors in IE/Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, polyfills

My React app works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but when I open it in Edge or Internet Explorer (>9), it does not appear and no error gets displayed in the console.

I've already tried to install babel-polyfill, but nothing changes.

**index.js**

```
import 'core-js';

...

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
...

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            ...
        ]
    }

};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["env", {
            "targets": {
                "browsers": [
                    "> 1%",
                    "last 2 versions"
                ]
            }
        }],
        "stage-2",
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "syntax-dynamic-import"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where are you including babel-polyfill?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus Now i fixed it. I added babel-polyfill to webpack.prod.js an not in the index.js. Thanks for the notice :)